# Extjs renderer method causing issues in Firefox

Tags: javascript, extjs

I got grid in a window and window opens up by button click event. It was working fine in firefox and IE. I just added renderer in columns, now it's not opening in firefox but has no issues in IE.

```
            {
            header : 'Notes Description',
            dataIndex : 'snotes_IsMandatory',
            width : 85,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : notesDescription
            }
```

and method is,

```
      function notesDescription(val, b, c, d, e, f){
      var result;
      if(val == 0)
        result = "false";
      else
        result = "true";

      return result;
      }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just commenting  //renderer : notesDescription it is working in firefox. so i can sure problem with renderer.

Comment: I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work unless the function is out of scope. Are there any errors in the console? Also, you could easily simplify that code: return `val === 0 ? 'false' : 'true';`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli : yep me too dont have any reasonable doubt.. no error. i debugged using visual studio. and i'm using firefox v23.

Comment: What I was implying, is that you need to post an example that demonstrates it "not working", since what you posted isn't enough. I'm betting you're just missing something simple that you'll figure out while making the test case.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli : and FYI it's working fine in IE and Chrome. only problem with firefox :(